# Disable keypress function when textarea has focus, re-enable function when textarea loses focus

Tags: javascript

I have a function which gets called on any keypress. 
On textarea focus I disable the keypress function. 
On textarea blur my keypress function call should be enabled again, but for some reason it is not.

This is the page: http://119.247.250.128/wasyoku/

```
function Kyprime()
{

            document.getElementById('q').onfocus = function() {return false};



            if (event.keyCode == 4) turn()              // control d
            if (event.keyCode == 126) hideframe()       // ~

            if (event.keyCode == 96) {                  // `
                parent.C.location = (parent.C.location  !=  wasyoku+"home/prime.html")
                ? "home/prime.html" : "n/FBwasyoku.html" }



    if ( parent.C.location != wasyoku + "ascii.html"  
    && parent.C.location   != wasyoku + "masterpiece/pagelet.html"
    && parent.C.location   != wasyoku + "masterpiece/artwork.html"
    && parent.C.location   != wasyoku + "masterpiece/webwork.html")
    {


        if (event.keyCode == 32)            // spacebar =
            parent.C.location = "../masterpiece/pageletNews.html"
        else if (event.keyCode == 3 | event.keyCode == 13)      // enter return
            parent.C.location = "../ascii.html"


};      document.onkeypress = Kyprime
```

How can I make my keypress function keep on working after textarea blur?

Comment: Improved Code format

Comment: explain code and problem pls

Comment: This doesn't really make sense as stated. What's the point of enabling key press only when the textarea doesn't have the focus?

Comment: all the keypress is set to function invoke, but when focus into textarea, those invoke should stop and return as normal typing text function. so when finish the textarea, it should resume its original status.

is that more clear for you guys（・・？

Answer (score 0):

You could create two event listeners to define whether your keypress event should trigger the Kyprime function or not:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('q');

textarea.addEventListener('blur', function() {
     document.onkeypress = Kyprime;
});
textarea.addEventListener('focus', function() {
     document.onkeypress = null;
});
```

Then on your Kyprime function you could remove this line:

```
document.getElementById('q').onfocus = function() {return false};
```

**WORKING EXAMPLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/czaj1a0s/1/

Comment: addEventListener doesn't go !
even use flag that  … 
var t = 0
function disKp() { t = 1  }
function resumeKp() { t = 0  }
document.onkeypress =  (t < 1) ?  Kyprime : null;

 nor if() to exclude all keypress.
it is either functions disabled or unable to type ╮"  ╯_╰╭"

Comment: The problem with this might be that you have the "document.onkeypress" being called only once at load time. Have you tried putting your "document.onkeypress" directly inside the disKP and resumeKP functions? You shouldn't need the "t" variable.